google sheets formula, filter unique while keeping the earliest data
I'm trying to remove duplicates from a simple table
4/1/2023    
6/1/2023    
7/1/2023    A
8/1/2023    A
9/1/2023    A
10/1/2023   B
9/15/2023   B
9/15/2023   B
12/19/2023  C
12/17/2023  C
12/19/2023  C
3/13/2024   D
3/13/2024   D

I want the result to look like this
4/1/2023    
7/1/2023    A
9/15/2023   B
12/17/2023  C
3/13/2024   D

Unique column B, while keep the earliest date for the entry
I tried query and filter and unique but still can't get it to work.

You can use:
=MAP(UNIQUE(B:B),LAMBDA(u,{MIN(FILTER(A:A,u=B:B)),u}))


QUERY() should work. Try-
=QUERY(A:B,"select B, min(A) where B is not null group by B")


